# How to show only one record in order grid for the same Order ID for parent configurable product and child simple product?

Tags: configurable-product, order-grid, simple-product

In order grid, two records with same Order ID are shown when the product is configurable product that has child product so-called simple product. I only want child product (simple product). I don't want parent product (configurable product). But the child simple product record only shows zero in Total column while the parent configurable product record shows total amount in **Total** column . What I want to get is the child simple product with the Total amount extracted from parent configurable product.[image: Order grid: Retrieving simple product, the child of configurable product]

```
<?php

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

    /*$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass()) 
        ->join(
            'sales/order_item',
            '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
            array(

                'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
                'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ", ")'),
                'qtys' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ", ")'),
                //'proptions' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.product_options SEPARATOR "<br><hr>")'),
            )



        ); */


     $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()

                       ->addFieldToSelect(array('order_id','sku','name','qty_ordered','product_id','product_options','row_total'))

                       //->setOrder('main_table.order_id', 'desc');
                       ->setOrder('main_table.created_at', 'desc');

        //  $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.order_id');



        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'),
            'main_table.order_id = sfog.entity_id',
            array('sfog.shipping_name','sfog.billing_name','sfog.increment_id')
        );

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),
            'sfo.entity_id=main_table.order_id',
            array('sfo.customer_email','sfo.weight',
            'sfo.discount_description','sfo.increment_id','sfo.store_id','sfo.created_at','sfo.status',
            'sfo.base_grand_total','sfo.grand_total')
        );

            //Join Invoice Grid
    $collection->getSelect()
           ->joinLeft(
            array('sfi' => 'sales_flat_invoice_grid'),
            'sfi.order_id= main_table.order_id',
            array(

                'sfi.increment_id as invoice_increment_id'
            )
        );

        /*//Product Options
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),
            'sfo.entity_id=main_table.order_id',
            array('sfo.customer_email','sfo.weight',
            'sfo.discount_description','sfo.increment_id','sfo.store_id','sfo.created_at','sfo.status',
            'sfo.base_grand_total','sfo.grand_total')
        );
        //Product Options */


        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    public function callback_skus($value, $row, $column, $isExport) {
        $_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($value)->getAllItems();

        $skus_arr = array();
        foreach ($_items as $item) {
            array_push($skus_arr, $item->getSku());
        }
        $skus_arr = array_unique($skus_arr);

        return implode("<br/>",$skus_arr);
    }

    public function callback_qtys($value, $row, $column, $isExport) {
        $_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($value)->getAllItems();

        $skus_arr = array();
        foreach ($_items as $item) {
            array_push($qtys_arr, $item->getQtyOrdered());
        }
        $skus_arr = array_unique($qtys_arr);

        return implode("<br/>",$qtys_arr);
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('invoice_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice #'),
            'index'     => 'invoice_increment_id',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'filter_index'=>'sfi.increment_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'filter_index' => 'sfog.increment_id',
        ));
    /*  $this->addColumn('tt', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Options'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'proptions',
            //'filter_index' => 'sfog.increment_id',
        ));*/
        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '50px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
            'filter_index' => 'sfog.billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('names', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
            'filter_index' => 'name',
        ));

        /*
        $this->addColumn('Options', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Option'),
            'index' => 'product_options',
            'filter_index' => 'product_options',
        ));*/



        $this->addColumn('Product Option', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Option'),
        'width'     => '150',
        'index'     => 'product_options',
        'filter_index' => 'product_options',
        'renderer' => new Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Renderer_Data()  // added this line
        ));



        $this->addColumn('qtys', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Quantity'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'type=' => 'text',
            'index' => 'qty_ordered',
            'filter_index' => 'qty_ordered',
            //'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_qtys') 
            //'renderer' => new Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Renderer_Date()
        ));

    /*  $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'align' => 'center',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.increment_id',
            'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_skus')
        ));*/

        $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'index' => 'sku',
            'align' => 'center',
            'filter_index' => 'sku',
        //  'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_skus')
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
            'index' => 'customer_email',
            'type' => 'text',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.customer_email',
        ));
      $this->addColumn('Total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
            'index' => 'row_total',
            'filter_index' => 'row_total',
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        /*$this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.grand_total',
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));*/

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.status',
            'type' => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id'
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
           // return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId())); 
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getOrderId())); 

        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you add the product name to the order grid? It's not available by default.

Comment: is it custom order grid where you want show order item???

Comment: it is not custom order grid. It is the existing order grid but we modified some by our own.

Comment: put your code...

Comment: if you have an order have three order items then what will be happan??it show three row or one row

Comment: Normally it only show three rows for three order items. When I order configure product that has child product, it shows four rows for three order items. I only want three rows for three order items.

Comment: I put my code as a question. Please kindly recheck the above question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naing,add parent id filter

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()

                       ->addFieldToSelect(array('order_id','sku','name','qty_ordered','product_id','product_options','row_total'))

                       //->setOrder('main_table.order_id', 'desc');
                       ->setOrder('main_table.created_at', 'desc');

        //  $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.order_id');
```

**To**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToSelect(array('order_id','sku','name','qty_ordered','product_id','product_options','row_total'))
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_item_id',array(
        'null' => true,
        ))->setOrder('main_table.created_at', 'desc');
```

Comment: Hi, Dear Amit Bera, thanks a lot. Your code works for me. I have one more question. Do you know how to load product option in order grid for configurable product. I know how to load product option for normal simple product. But I do not know how to load product option for configurable product in order grid. Thank you for your help

Comment: I am not clear with your comment. May I know what do you mean to accept by answer for quality?